# asm compilation C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly

I have a small program in C that uses the asm() function to use assembly instructions. However, at the time of compilation, it gives me a link error that I can't correct. Indeed as the use of -m32 is necessary in order to use the instruction 'move' I think that it is wrong 'lib' to use.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myJump.h"

static struct ctx_s pctx_buf;

int main() {
    int prod1;
    prod1 = mul(0);
    printf("prod1 = %d\n", prod1);

    int prod2;
    prod2 = tryIt(&pctx_buf, shintMule, 0);
    printf("prod2 = %d\n", prod2);
}
```

myJump.c:

```
#include "myJump.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define CTXMAGIC 0x73478336

static int thr;
static struct ctx_s pctx_buf;

int mul(int d) {
    int i;
    switch (scanf("%d", &i)) {
        case EOF:
            return 1;
        case 0:
            return mul(d + 1);
        case 1:
            if (i) {
                return i * mul(d + 1);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

int tryIt(struct ctx_s *pctx, funct_t *f, int arg) {
    copyBuf(*pctx);
    asm("movl %0, %%esp"
    :
    :"r"(pctx->ctx_esp));

    asm("movl %0, %%ebp"
    :
    :"r"(pctx->ctx_ebp));

    pctx->ctx_magic = CTXMAGIC;
    return f(arg);
}

void copyBuf(struct ctx_s pctx){
    pctx_buf.ctx_ebp = pctx.ctx_ebp;
    pctx_buf.ctx_esp = pctx.ctx_esp;
    pctx_buf.ctx_magic = pctx.ctx_magic;
}

int throwIt(struct ctx_s *pctx, int r) {
    assert( pctx->ctx_magic == CTXMAGIC );
    thr = r;
    asm("movl %%esp, %0"
    :"=r"(pctx->ctx_esp));
    asm("movl %%ebp, %0"
    :"=r"(pctx->ctx_ebp));
    return thr;
}

int shintMule(int d) {
    int i;
    switch (scanf("%d", &i)) {
        case EOF:
            return 1;
        case 0:
            return mul(d + 1);
        case 1:
            if (i) {
                return i * mul(d + 1);
            } else {
                throwIt(&pctx_buf, 0);
            }
    }

}
```

MAKEFILE:

```
all : main

main : main.o myJump

main.o : main.c myJump.h
    gcc -c -O2 -Wall -march='x86-64' main.c

myJump : myJump.o

myJump.o : myJump.c myJump.h
    gcc -c -O2 -Wall -march='x86-64' -m32 myJump.c
    
clean : 
    rm *.o main
```

The error after make all:

```
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -march='x86-64' main.c
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -march='x86-64' -m32 myJump.c
cc   myJump.o   -o myJump
/usr/bin/ld : architecture i386 du fichier d'entrée « %B » est incompatible avec la sortie ЛZV�U
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o : dans la fonction « _start » :
(.text+0x20) : référence indéfinie vers « main »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<commande interne> : myJump] Erreur 1
```

**EDIT1:** pass to 64bits

main.c:
the printf it's for debug

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myJump.h"


int main() {
    int prod1;
    prod1 = mul(0);
    printf("prod1 = %d\n", prod1);
    
    printf("0");
    struct ctx_s pctx_buf;
    int prod2;
    printf("1");
    prod2 = tryIt(&pctx_buf, shintMule, 0);
    printf("10");
    printf("prod2 = %d\n", prod2);
}
```

myJump.c:

```
#include "myJump.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define CTXMAGIC 0xDEADBEAF

static int thr;
static struct ctx_s pctx_buf;

int mul(int d) {
    int i;
    switch (scanf("%d", &i)) {
        case EOF:
            return 1;
        case 0:
            return mul(d + 1);
        case 1:
            if (i) {
                return i * mul(d + 1);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

int tryIt(struct ctx_s *pctx, funct_t *f, int arg) {
    copyBuf(*pctx);
    asm("mov %0, %%rsp"
    :
    :"r"(pctx->ctx_rsp));

    asm("mov %0, %%rbp"
    :
    :"r"(pctx->ctx_rbp));

    pctx->ctx_magic = CTXMAGIC;
    return f(arg);
}

void copyBuf(struct ctx_s pctx){
    pctx_buf.ctx_rbp = pctx.ctx_rbp;
    pctx_buf.ctx_rsp = pctx.ctx_rsp;
    pctx_buf.ctx_magic = pctx.ctx_magic;
}

int throwIt(struct ctx_s *pctx, int r) {
    assert( pctx->ctx_magic == CTXMAGIC );
    thr = r;
    asm("mov %%rsp, %0"
    :"=r"(pctx->ctx_rsp));
    asm("mov %%rbp, %0"
    :"=r"(pctx->ctx_rbp));
    return thr;
}

int shintMule(int d) {
    int i;
    switch (scanf("%d", &i)) {
        case EOF:
            return 1;
        case 0:
            return mul(d + 1);
        case 1:
            if (i) {
                return i * mul(d + 1);
            } else {
                throwIt(&pctx_buf, 0);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to link `myJump` as a seperate executable? Based on what I see here, `main : main.o myJump` should be `main : main.o myJump.o` and `myJump : myJump.o` should be removed.

Comment: You're also compiling `myJump.c` as 32-bit `i386`, but then not linking as 32-bit, which is the first of the two errors from `ld`.

Comment: @ThomasJager ok the 
>/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o : dans la fonction « _start » :
(.text+0x20) : référence indéfinie vers « main »
is modifie and is ok 
but the first error of architecture i386 continue.  You think need to use -march=i386 ?

Comment: If you're on a 64-bit bit system, you should probably be building for `x86_64` unless you have a reason not to. What's the reason for going 32-bit? I would think that you'd want to drop `-m32`, and use the proper `rsp` register instead of `esp`. (and use 64-bit register fields in all those context structures.

Comment: I use the -m32 option because otherwise I get an error saying that the mov instruction is not supported

Comment: Oh wait rsp is the esp but for 64bit ?

Comment: `esp` does still exist, but it's only the lower 32 bits of `rsp`. Similarly, `rbp` is the entire 64-bit register, with `ebp` being the low 32 bits of it. The code in `myJump.c` should likely be rewritten to use x86_64 instead of i386. You'd need to replace all fields used in `ctx_s` with the correct ones, and using the correct instructions. `movl` is incorrect in that context.

Comment: ok thanks for all.
now I can launch my main but have a segmentation Error ...
new Error

Comment: It's hard to know why that's happening without seeing the code.

Comment: it's the same code but now the `esp -> rsp`, `ebp -> rbp` ans the instruction `movl -> mov`
the seg fault start befor the end of `printf("prod1 = %d\n", prod1);` in the main

Comment: I'd suggest showing updated code, it's impossible to help without that.

Comment: The new code it's in EDIT1 
in the makefile I delete the -m32

Comment: I've compiled what you've got, and the main problem I'm seeing now is that you can't expect changing the stack pointer to work properly while in a C function. The compiler can implicitly store values on the stack, and compiling this for myself, it does.

Comment: So you think it's not possible to do context switching in C or not in this way?

Comment: It could be done, but it would ideally do both saving and restoring within a single `asm` block, with a parameter that tells it which to do. Having a single `asm` block means that, on restore, the stack frame will look as it did on save. However, it would often be better to have a separate assembly file that performs the context switch.

Comment: Ok I try to just print the %%rsp value. But we have a seg fault.

`void* cp(){
 int src = 10;
 void* dst;
 
 asm("mov %0, %%rsp \n\t"
 :"=r" (dst)
 );
 
 return dst;
}


int main() {
 //int prod1;
    //prod1 = mul(0);
    //printf("prod1 = %d\n", prod1);
 
 printf("0\n");
 printf("%p\n",cp());
 
}`

Comment: by the way, thank you @ThomasJager

Comment: BTW, `-march='x86-64'` doesn't do what you think: it sets `-mtune=generic` and options like `-msse2` to their baseline defaults for any x86-64 CPU.  It's unrelated and orthogonal to `-m32` and `-m64`.  e.g. `-m32 -march=x86-64` would make 32-bit code that can use SSE and SSE2, even if your GCC was configured for those not to be on by default for 32-bit code.  See [Can code built with g++ -march=x86-64 run on a 32-bit Operating System?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65791228)

Comment: As @ThomasJager says, this is likely to be pretty flaky messing around with changing RSP and RBP in an `asm` statement.  Especially since `-fomit-frame-pointer` is on by default at `-O2` and maybe even `-O1`.  It's also not supported for an `asm` statement to change RSP at all, or to change RBP without telling the compiler.  Or to modify space below RSP (the red-zone).  Make your context switch look to the compiler like an opaque function call that *eventually* returns following the calling convention/ABI (after having set RSP to a different stack and done stuff there); put it in a separate .s