# For gcc compiler, what x86-64 instruction set does gcc target when you compile without any flags versus -O2?

Tags: gcc, x86-64, compiler-optimization, simd

For x86-64 there are lots of instruction sets that speed up code execution. Here is a list from gcc wiki https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning:

- MMX
- SSE
- SSE2
- SSE3
- SSSE3
- SSE4.1
- SSE4.2
- POPCNT
- AVX
- AVX2

#### For gcc compiler, what x86-64 instruction set does gcc target when you compile without any flags versus `-O2`?

To keep things simple lets just say the question is about gcc version 12 (most recent major). But I would like to know what gcc command switches/options i need to do to so that i can see what my version of gcc version does.

I assume that gcc chooses something that is "portable" so that would mean probably something slow. But this is just my assumption... I would like to know does that mean like SSE4.2 or none?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't pass a command-line `-march` option, then you get whatever was selected when gcc was compiled.  The default is `-march=x86-64` but it could have been overridden by whoever compiled your gcc (e.g. your binary package distributor).  See https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html and note the `--with-arch` option.

You can compile with `-v -Q` to see what option is in use.  Look for the `options passed` line.

With `-march=x86-64` you get "least common denominator" code that will run on every known x86-64 CPU, all the way back to the AMD K8.  This includes SSE2, which was part of the original AMD64 spec, but not SSE3 or anything later.  `popcnt` would not be included either.

The `-march` option is orthogonal to optimization options like `-O2` and the `-f...` flags (e.g. `-funroll-loops`).  You always get code compatible with whatever is selected by `-march`, no matter what optimization options are in use.  However `-m` flags (like `-mavx`) can permit the use of other CPU features beyond what `-march` implies, in which case your code is only guaranteed to run on CPUs with those features.

Comment: on my VM `rocky8`, `gcc -v -Q` has `--with-arch_32=x86-64`: so i guess that is the default `-march` that my compiler was built for. i search for documentation on `x86-64` and found  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html . which is similar to your description.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: I would guess that `--with-arch-32` only applies to compilations using the `-m32` option.  It's a bit weird that this is `x86-64` but I guess that means it should run in the 32-bit mode of all x86 CPUs that support 64-bit mode.  My compiler has `--with-arch-32=i686`, so `-m32` code would run on a Pentium Pro but not on a Pentium or a 486.  Obviously neither of them would support 64-bit code at all.

Comment: i seem to recall that RHEL distro (Rocky is a source copy and rebuild of RHEL) dropped support for 32bit. so maybe that is why that value is `x86-64`. not sure.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: That makes sense; `gcc -m32` on a distro that doesn't support installing on purely-32-bit systems might as well assume the same set of features that are baseline for x86-64, since even 32-bit binaries built for that version of that distro can only be running on systems with SSE2 + 686 features like CMOV, and other `-march=x86-64` features.  (see [Can code built with g++ -march=x86-64 run on a 32-bit Operating System?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65791228) for more about what `gcc -m32 -march=x86-64` means; it's pretty much `-march=k8` but without `-mtune=k8`)

Comment: according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11739573) the default `march` value is from the field `target`. you can get the value in two ways `gcc -dumpmachine` or `gcc -v|grep 'Target:'`. on debian11 gcc-10 the value is `x86_64-linux-gnu`. on rocky8 gcc-8 the value is `x86_64-redhat-linux`. split the string on `-` then take the first word which is `x86_64`. do you agree @NateEldredge?